# sql query date difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do something I don't know if it's doable. I have this query:

SELECT [CreatedOn]
  FROM [MyTable]

[image: printscreen]

As you can see in the image, there are different dates. Now what I want to achieve is to get the time difference between each date/time in each row. For example, diference between date in row1 and row2, then row2 and row3, etc...
Is that possible?
Thanks, Laziale

Comment: LEAD and LAG functions can do this.

Comment: @Randy : However we need to wait until SQLServer 2012 released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH q AS (
SELECT
    CreatedOn,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedOn) AS rn
FROM
    MyTable
)
SELECT
    q1.CreatedOn AS Date,
    q2.CreatedOn AS NextDate,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, q1.CreatedOn, q2.CreatedOn) AS SecondDiff
FROM 
    q q1 JOIN
    q q2 ON q1.rn + 1 = q2.rn
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a cte with row number then outer join on the next row to get the datediff

```
;with t as (
    SELECT 
        [CreatedOn],
        rn = row_number() over(order by [CreatedOn])
    FROM 
        [MyTable]
)

select
    t.[CreatedOn],
    secondsTilNext = datediff(s, t.[CreatedOn], tnext.[CreatedOn])
from
    t
    left outer join t tnext on tnext.rn = t.rn + 1
```

Comment: what does s stands for? I am getting error here: http://gyazo.com/a88835cb955dedd5785b9a3b833717e1

Comment: @Laziale `s` stands for seconds... it will give you the number of seconds between your two dates.  You're getting that error because you need a `,` after `t.[CreatedOn]` in your `select`.

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson whoops, thanks for edit...you deserve answer now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C# to access your data, there is a good reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287590(v=vs.71).aspx

Basically, the code is

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2002,7,15);
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Now;
// Difference in days, hours, and minutes.
TimeSpan ts = newDate - oldDate;
// Difference in days.
int differenceInDays = ts.Days;
```

Any .NET language you use should support something similar to this.  I've done the same thing in Python many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try datediff [MSDN Datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Or perhaps

```
    cast((date1-date2) as varchar(255))
```

Syntax might be wrong, I can't check it at the moment.